# How to use configuration variables on validation rules in elequent model?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-validation

How I can use config variable in validation rules?
This is my **model.php**

```
public static $rules = [
        'transaction_limit_per_day' => 'required|numeric|max:'.config('agripoints.cropAgentTransactionLimit')
];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use any variable inside laravel validation rules using double quotes like you would do in normal double quote string.

```
$transaction_limit = config('agripoints.cropAgentTransactionLimit');

public static $rules = [ 
       'transaction_limit_per_day' => "required|numeric|max:$transaction_limit" 
];
```